# How do i update the paint event after an X or Y position has changed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, paint, repaint

At the moment I can get a small red box to appear in the top left of my screen and I have some code that increases and decreases the values of their respective variables through a key listener. The problem is when I change the value of a variable for X and Y it doesn't show that change on screen, it just stays there in the corner no matter what.

What is the solution to updating the form display to show the red box as it moves and is there a more efficient way so that it only updates the display once a key has been pressed?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MovingObject
{
    public partial class ObjectMove : Form
    {
        public ObjectMove() => InitializeComponent();    

        public void FillRectangleRectangle(PaintEventArgs e) { 
            SolidBrush blackPen = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);            
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x: Program.XCoord ,y: Program.YCoord, 10, 10);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blackPen, rect);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
            FillRectangleRectangle(e);
        }

        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Up)
            {
                Program.YCoord+=10;
            }

            if (keyData == Keys.Down)
            {
                Program.YCoord-=10;
            }

            if (keyData == Keys.Left)
            {
                Program.XCoord-=10;
            }

            if (keyData == Keys.Right)
            {
                Program.XCoord+=10;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try adding `base.OnPaint()` to the `OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)`. Not sure that it is causing the problem, but at least it is the correct way to override the [OnPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint?view=netframework-4.8) method, so it won't hurt to try.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what does base.OnPaint() actually do cause it displays without it?

Comment: It calls the base class (`Form`) implementation of `OnPaint()`.  It's a matter of _replacing_ the existing implementation (not calling `base.OnPaint()`) vs. _augmenting_ it (calling `base.OnPaint()`).  According to @EugenePodskal's documentation link, inheritors (i.e. you) should call the base implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the system that the form needs to be re-rendered after updating your variables:

```
this.Invalidate()
```